# Does Oracle support full text search?

Tags: oracle, full-text-search, oracle-text

Is there an Oracle equivalent to MS SQL's full text search service?

If so, has anyone implemented it and had good / bad experiences?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[Oracle Text](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/content.htm#sthref2643) is the equivalent functionality.

I've had good experiences with it.  Assuming that you are maintaining the text index asynchronously, that tends to be the first source of problems, since it may be a bit between a change being made and the index getting updated, but that's normally quite reasonable during normal operation.

Comment: We found Oracle's update of the index to be vastly superior to SQL Servers. SQLServer 2005, the indexing is a separate app that you have to manually invoke.

Comment: @JustinCave Could you please provide some learning resources for Oracle Full Text Search? It seems that there is not so many good books on this topic.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to what Justin said, you can find more information about Oracle Text [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/index-098492.html).

Answer (score 2):

And further to what Justin said, it is possible to create the index so it updates on commit, although this is not recommended for large amounts of text.

It offers much more power than a simple LIKE compare against %string%.