# DevArt dotConnect for Oracle - how to do a WHERE LIKE clause with a parameter?

Tags: .net, oracle, where-clause, devart

How do I do a `WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%SearchTerm%'` with the [DevArt dotConnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) libraries?

Ideally using a `CommandParameter` for the SearchTerm?

**I've tried the following with no joy:**

```
cmd.CommandText =
  "SELECT ID, COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B FROM TABLE_A
   WHERE COLUMN_A LIKE :SearchTerm";
```

**I've got it working with:**

```
cmd.CommandText =
  "SELECT ID, COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B FROM TABLE_A
   WHERE COLUMN_A LIKE :SearchTerm";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SearchTerm", "%" + term.Replace('%', ' ') + "%");
```

But I'm not happy with encasing the term with `%` signs - is there a correct or better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
cmd.CommandText =
  "SELECT ID, COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B
   FROM TABLE_A
   WHERE COLUMN_A LIKE '%' || :SearchTerm || '%'";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SearchTerm", term);
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle itself doesn't like "Where column LIKE %:searchterm%", so if you need the wildcards in there then they need to be added as part of the parameter.

You could avoid it by setting up a [full text index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202623/does-oracle-support-full-text-search) on the column you want to search and then use CONTAINS instead, which doesn't require the wildcards. It's also a more powerful search method, but more complex to set up.

Comment: The same goes for most ADO drivers. `%` should always be in the parameter.