# How to create text index for '%abc%' search?

Tags: sql, oracle, full-text-search, indexing

I'd like to index queries like `x like '%abc%'`

If I have a table like the following

```
create table t
(
  data varchar(100)
);
```

I want to create an index to be able to do the following efficiently:

```
select * from t where contains('%abc%');
```

And this:

```
select * from t where contains('abc%');
```

I also want this table to be updated live.

How do I create such an index? (I have a feeling I need a `ctxcat` index, but I'm confused about what options I need to give it)

I'm using Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use this (set you min and max length to appropiate values)

```
BEGIN
    ctx_ddl.create_preference  ('FT_WL', 'BASIC_WORDLIST');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute      ('FT_WL', 'substring_index',   'YES');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute      ('FT_WL', 'prefix_index',      'YES');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute      ('FT_WL', 'prefix_min_length', 1);
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute      ('FT_WL', 'prefix_max_length', 6);
  END;

CREATE INDEX fulltext_idx ON tmp_fulltext (fulltext)
 INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CTXCAT
 PARAMETERS ('WORDLIST FT_WL')
```

The parameters are explained here [Oracle Text Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/text.901/a90121/cdatadi6.htm)

and see this question on how to manage the refresh and how the index may not be quicker than a full scan with high cardinality data:

[PL/SQL Performance Tuning for LIKE '%...%' Wildcard Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229445/pl-sql-performance-tuning-for-like-wildcard-queries)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a few questions: Is `prefix_index` for `abc%` queries and 'substring_index' for `%abc%` queries? And does the substring index by default index all substrings? Also, how do I use this index? Will `contains(col, '%abc%')` and `contains(col, 'abc%')` do the trick?

Comment: Yes those searches will work, have updated with a link that can explain it better than me, but essentially the parameters are used to improve the performance of exactly that type of search.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create an environment before you can create domain indexes. You need to have `ctxsys` user and necessary `ctxapp` privileges to create it. [Follow the steps explained in this link to have one for your environment](https://web.archive.org/web/20130517115450/http://www.oraclebin.com/2012/12/creating-environment-for-ctxsys.html). This user is not created by default while installing Oracle.

Once you have the all the grants and packages you can create preferences and index as shown.

```
SQL> begin
  2  ctx_ddl.create_preference('SUBSTRING_PREF', 'BASIC_WORDLIST');
  3  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('SUBSTRING_PREF', 'SUBSTRING_INDEX','TRUE');
  4  end;
  5  /
```

Now create a domain index as shown.

```
 SQL> create index test_idx on test(object_name)
   2  indextype is ctxsys.context parameters ('wordlist SUBSTRING_PREF MEMORY 50M');

Index created.

select * from test where contains( object_name,'%EXEC%') > 0;
```

See the link below which explains this with the execution plan. **Update 2018:** The original link is dead and not backed up on archive.org, unfortunately.

<strike>http://www.oraclebin.com/2012/12/oracle-text-and-domain-indexes.html</strike>

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your problem if your database is big then you can use [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html)

Sphinx is an open source full text search server, designed from the ground up with performance, relevance (aka search quality), and integration simplicity in mind. It's written in C++ and works on Linux (RedHat, Ubuntu, etc), Windows, MacOS, Solaris, FreeBSD, and a few other systems

Comment: This looks interesting, but sadly I'm stuck with Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in Oracle only if you have intermedia/Oracle Text option on the server...

For your example you could use

```
create index t_index_data on t(data) 
indextype is ctxsys.context 
parameters ('DATASTORE CTXSYS.DEFAULT_DATASTORE');
```

I am not sure if you need to change the type from `varchar2(100)` to `clob` .

For details and options/example regarding this sort of indexes see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/text.901/a90122/ind4.htm

Comment: Are you sure this indexes substrings? I read the document, and it seems like I need a "preference" "SUBSTRING_INDEX" or something. Can you give a code example that does what I'm looking for including the substring index?

Comment: you could be right regarding the preference - I don't have an Oracle server with those options available so I can't test it...