# What are the Oracle equalent Functions of MySql Match Against

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have been searching for Oracle functions that are equivalent to to MySql Match Against.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: They don't exist. There's `LIKE`, regexes, and more of those features (which MySQL supports as well), but the FULLTEXT index of MySQL (MyISAM to be more precise) doesn't exist in Oracle, and that is what is used for `MATCH AGAINST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a `WHERE` condition this does not exist but the main advantage when you use `MATCH AGAINST` is that you use a `FULLTEXT` index and that exits in Oracle also and is called Oracle Text. See the following answer: [Does Oracle support full text search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202623/does-oracle-support-full-text-search) or make a general search for "Oracle Text".