# In Oracle, DBMS_LOB.INSTR vs LIKE '%keyword%'

Tags: sql, oracle

In a few posts, most say INSTR is faster. (Of course, it depends on the situation.)

In the following cases, I wonder whether I should continue to use INSTR or how to optimize it.

**CASE 1.**

`SELECT *
FROM TB1, TB2
WHERE TB1.PKID = TB2.P_PKID`

The result is displayed immediately when you inquire.

**CASE 2.**

`SELECT *
FROM TB1, TB2
WHERE TB1.PKID = TB2.P_PKID
AND DBMS_LOB.INSTR(TB2.CONTENTS, 'KEYWORD')>0`

But, it takes 10 seconds to search the contents(CLOB Type) using INSTR.

**CASE 3.**

`SELECT *
FROM TB1, TB2
WHERE TB1.PKID = TB2.P_PKID
AND TB2.CONTENTS LIKE '%KEYWORD%'`

Using LIKE takes 22 seconds.

The total number of data is about 100,000.

I just wonder if I should continue to use INSTR, or is there another way?

Comment: If you want to check for `KEYWORD` appearing anywhere inside the contents, then `INSTR` and `LIKE` both seem like viable options.  What makes you want to not use either method?

Comment: can you execute every query multiple times and measure time?

Comment: @IlyaBursov Running multiple times is always similar.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What does it mean to use both INSTR and LIKE?

Comment: What I'm asking is, what is your question?  If you have search for text inside a column, then what you are doing is the best way, unless you want to maybe consider full text search or something along those lines.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am sorry that English is poor. The point of the question is, when I use INSTR and LIKE, I wonder if INSTR is faster than LIKE. But I wonder if there is a better search method because INSTR takes 10 seconds too.

Comment: Oracle has a `REGEXP_LIKE` as well, but I expect that would be slower than both `INSTR` and `LIKE`.  Go with `INSTR` if it meets your performance needs.  Generally, base string functions will outperform like/regex approaches.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In the end, according to you, INSTR seems to be the best. I have to use it as it is now. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The only other option which comes to mind is full text search.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm sorry, but I don't understand what the full text search method means

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202623/does-oracle-support-full-text-search

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was just watching that article. Is it possible for Oracle to use version 12 or higher? If so, I think it's hard to use because the Oracle version of the system I'm using is 10G.

Comment: @eastglow - Oracle Text has been around since the 8.1 days.  You should have no problem using it with Oracle 10g.

Comment: The answer to your question (is it better to use DBMS_LOB.INSTR or LIKE or perhaps even plain INSTR) depends on your Oracle version. I have never worked on version 10, but you can run a few tests. It is entirely possible that the fastest you can do for some query is 10 seconds, depending on how large the CLOB(s) is/are.